# How do you do Canvas Authentication client-side for a Javascript application?

Tags: oauth, canvas, react

I am trying to build out a PoC of what will eventually be a nodeJS+React application that will be embedded in Salesforce via Canvas.

I'd like to get the PoC up and running with just React. What would be the right authentication approach for Canvas if this is all client-side?

I'm thinking oauth user-agent but have the connected app not return the refresh token.

Also, are there any good examples of this flow in Javascript? The [canvas developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_oauth_code_example.htm) has very little sample code and the [canvas JS SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK) isn't that well documented. Haven't found any examples of this in React.